# How do you create a barplot with data from a single column?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I would like to create a barplot from a single column with 1682 entries. All of the entries are numbers 1-10 or 96-98, and I'd like to create a barplot that groups the data according to those 14 values. For example, there are 50 rows with value 1, 28 rows, with value 2, 135 rows with value 3, etc. and I want to represent that in a plot.

In essence, a barplot with 14 columns, where each column is labelled 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 96, 97, 98.

How would I do this? Feel free to direct me to an existing question that covers this topic – I haven't been able to find one, but I'm very new to R and very slowly figuring things out.

Comment: are you looking for something like `hist(x)`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `table` and `barplot`

```
df <- data.frame(x = sample(c(1:10, 96:98), 50, TRUE))

barplot(table(df$x))
```

[image]

Or use `hist` if you'd like the numeric spacing between the x-values reflected on the x-axis

```
hist(df$x, breaks = diff(range(df$x)))
```

[image]

Comment: The first one is perfect, thank you so much!! This may be a really silly question, but what would I modify to actually fit my own dataset? Like, how would I use this on my existing column/dataset? Thanks again!

Comment: You should be able to just change “df” to the name of your data.frame and “x” to the name of the column in your data frame you want to plot. But, it is suggested to share an example data frame when asking a question so that answers can use that and it will be more clear how the answers go from data to output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data.table:

```
library(data.table)

# create random data:
set.seed(1)
x = sample(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 96, 97, 98), 1682, TRUE)

# convert to data.table
x = as.data.table(x)

# load ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

# plot. This produces ugly results as bars have a wide space between them
ggplot(x[, .N, by = x], aes(x = x, y = N))+geom_col()

# alternative plotting
ggplot(x[, .N, by = x], aes(x = factor(x), y = N))+geom_col()
```

`x[, .N, by = x]` is data.table syntax for counting (.N) the number of rows for each unique item in column `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Here a `tidyverse` solution:

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Example data

```
df <-
  tibble(
    x = round(runif(1000,0,50))
  )
```

### Code

```
df %>% 
  #Count number of observations for each value of x
  count(x) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = n))+
  geom_col()
```

#### Output

[image]